# Move the sprite but don't collide with other sprites in the scene in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm referring to the official example on [Phaser.io site](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/tilesprite), but have copied it here for reference below. What I want, and repeatedly fail to achieve is that the moving (with keyboard keys) `starfield` sprite would not collide with other `vegies` sprites.

I did go through the docs and looked here on SO and their forum, and it seems that the solutions should be easy enough; to just put the following code in the `update()` function:

```
game.world.bringToTop(sprite);
```

But, for some reason this is not working for me, so please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {

 game.load.image('sky', 'assets/skies/sky4.png');
    game.load.image('starfield', 'assets/misc/starfield.jpg');
    game.load.spritesheet('veggies', 'assets/sprites/fruitnveg64wh37.png', 64, 64);

}

var sprite;
var cursors;
var veggies;

function create() {

    game.add.image(0, 0, 'sky');

 // Enable p2 physics
 game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

    //  Make things a bit more bouncey
    game.physics.p2.defaultRestitution = 0.8;

    //  Add a sprite
    sprite = game.add.tileSprite(300, 450, 200, 50, 'starfield');

    //  Enable if for physics. This creates a default rectangular body.
 game.physics.p2.enable(sprite);

    veggies = game.add.group();
    veggies.enableBody = true;
    veggies.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;

    var vegFrames = [ 1, 3, 4, 8 ];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var veg = veggies.create(game.world.randomX, game.world.randomY, 'veggies', game.rnd.pick(vegFrames));
        veg.body.setCircle(26);
    }

    text = game.add.text(20, 20, 'move with arrow keys', { fill: '#ffffff' });

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

}

function update() {

 sprite.body.setZeroVelocity();
 game.world.bringToTop(veggies);

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveLeft(400);
        sprite.tilePosition.x -= 8;
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveRight(400);
        sprite.tilePosition.x += 8;
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveUp(400);
        sprite.tilePosition.y -= 8;
    }
    else if (cursors.down.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveDown(400);
        sprite.tilePosition.y += 8;
    }

}
```

**edit:** Solution which worked in the end thanks to SirSandman's answer:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

function preload() {

    game.load.image('stars', 'assets/misc/starfield.jpg');
    game.load.spritesheet('ship', 'assets/sprites/humstar.png', 32, 32);
    game.load.image('panda', 'assets/sprites/spinObj_01.png');
    game.load.image('sweet', 'assets/sprites/spinObj_06.png');

}

var ship;
var starfield;
var cursors;

function create() {

    //  Enable P2
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

    //  Turn on impact events for the world, without this we get no collision callbacks
    game.physics.p2.setImpactEvents(true);

    game.physics.p2.restitution = 0.8;

    //  Create our collision groups. One for the player, one for the pandas
    var playerCollisionGroup = game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
    var pandaCollisionGroup = game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();

    //  This part is vital if you want the objects with their own collision groups to still collide with the world bounds
    //  (which we do) - what this does is adjust the bounds to use its own collision group.
    game.physics.p2.updateBoundsCollisionGroup();

    starfield = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'stars');
    starfield.fixedToCamera = true;

    var pandas = game.add.group();
    pandas.enableBody = true;
    pandas.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var panda = pandas.create(game.world.randomX, game.world.randomY, 'panda');
        panda.body.setRectangle(40, 40);

        //  Tell the panda to use the pandaCollisionGroup 
        panda.body.setCollisionGroup(pandaCollisionGroup);

        //  Pandas will collide against themselves and the player
        //  If you don't set this they'll not collide with anything.
        //  The first parameter is either an array or a single collision group.
        panda.body.collides(pandaCollisionGroup);
        panda.body.velocity.x = 500;
        panda.body.velocity.y = 500;
    }

    //  Create our ship sprite
    ship = game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'ship');
    ship.scale.set(2);
    ship.smoothed = false;
    ship.animations.add('fly', [0,1,2,3,4,5], 10, true);
    ship.play('fly');

    game.physics.p2.enable(ship, false);
    ship.body.setCircle(28);
    ship.body.fixedRotation = true;

    //  Set the ships collision group
    ship.body.setCollisionGroup(playerCollisionGroup);

    //  The ship will collide with the pandas, and when it strikes one the hitPanda callback will fire, causing it to alpha out a bit
    //  When pandas collide with each other, nothing happens to them.
    
    game.camera.follow(ship);

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

}

function hitPanda(body1, body2) {

    //  body1 is the space ship (as it's the body that owns the callback)
    //  body2 is the body it impacted with, in this case our panda
    //  As body2 is a Phaser.Physics.P2.Body object, you access its own (the sprite) via the sprite property:
    body2.sprite.alpha -= 0.1;

}

function update() {

    ship.body.setZeroVelocity();

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveLeft(200);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveRight(200);
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveUp(200);
    }
    else if (cursors.down.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveDown(200);
    }

    if (!game.camera.atLimit.x)
    {
        starfield.tilePosition.x += (ship.body.velocity.x * 16) * game.time.physicsElapsed;
    }

    if (!game.camera.atLimit.y)
    {
        starfield.tilePosition.y += (ship.body.velocity.y * 16) * game.time.physicsElapsed;
    }

}

function render() {

    game.debug.text('Collide with the Pandas!', 32, 32);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I P2 you have to set the Collisiongroups in contrast to arcarde.
I think you have to set a collisiongroup for the sprite like that:

```
 var veggCollisionGroup = game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
```

and then define with which other groups this group shell collide like that in the Loop:

```
veggies.body.setCollisionGroup(veggCollisionGroup);
veggies.body.collides(veggCollisionGroup);
```

And then the your tilesprite should collide with your other tilesprites.

Source:
http://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/collision-groups
if i should be wrong you will find your answer in the examples. :)

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct since you pointed me in the right direction. I updated my own post with the exact solution that I used in the end, just in case it helps someone in the future.